# Artifacts in Render which actually don't exists geometrically

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, geometry

I have a plane which had a Boolean with a text converted to mesh.
This is the render
There are visible imperfections in this which i think are called artifacts but i can be wrong

[image]

These imperfections don't exist in the geometrical form , which means there is no geometry there , just a flat plain

**All modifiers on the planes are applied**
im using the Cycles rendering engine

[image]

Also visible there are no other objects in the scene causing any interceptions , so how is this happening.
Imerfections are also not visible in the render mode in blender

Comment: Even Jedh's answer is correct ... I just tried your typo with different font ... and I don't have the normal issue. Is it possible your plane is not precisely flat? Before applying modifiers, ensure your plane is flat select vertices and Scale on Z axis to zero.

Comment: These artefacts generates usually Smooth shading, so switch to Flat or enable Data Properties > Normals > Auto Smooth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could come from having to little geometry on your plane.
Basically Blender shows you editable points which we consider geo but uses triangles to compute the mesh. (not the most accurate description but oh well...)

Your boolean creates very long triangles which aren't displayed in the viewport but create problems in the render.

To fix this you can just subdivide the plane a bunch of times before applying the boolean.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @SHikhaMittal Right ... by default boolean generates a BMesh (n-gon - face with more than four corners) just for rendering it's triangulated. Aalso you can actually preview them if you add Triangulate modifier.

Comment: Or wireframe node in the shader editor